# How to combine two tables with common headers in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to combine two tables with common headers. The formula below only properly works, if I define the exact start and end row. How can I adjust the formula below to dynamically fetch non blank rows from both the tables.

```
=iferror({A1:C50;ArrayFormula(hlookup(A1:C1,'Settings'!A1:C50,row(A2:A50),0))})
```

Sample Input:

Table 1

| col 1 | col2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 789 |
| def | 456 | 1212 |

Table 2

| col 1 | col2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 78849 |
| jkl | 256 | 1298 |

Desired Output:

Table 3

| col 1 | col2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 789 |
| def | 456 | 1212 |
| abc | 123 | 78849 |
| jkl | 256 | 1298 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OUERY`:

```
=QUERY({A1:C1;A2:C;E2:G},"WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL")
```

[image]